# executable file in /usr/local/bin

Tags: path

When I type `echo $PATH`, I can see `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/bin:/opt/X11/bin` so it means /usr/local/bin is in my PATH and I have executable files in this directory. But when I type `whereis filename`, which is under /usr/local/bin, it does not show the path. However, when I type whereis `filename`, which is under /usr/bin, it shows the PATH `/usr/bin/filename`. I want to run my executable files located in /usr/local/bin without typing the whole PATH, how can I do this? Right now, only the files in /usr/bin can run without typing the whole PATH.

Comment: Is the file under /usr/local/bin executable by you ?

Comment: @ Brian Agnew Yes, I can. Sorry, I thought if you cannot see whereis, the file will not be executable. However, why I cannot see the PATH, when I type 'whereis filename' for those files under usr/local/bin